# MongoDB - How to fix high CPU usage

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, pymongo, database

I'm a MongoDB / PyMongo newbie. I've noticed that MongoDB uses a lot of CPU (in htop) and narrowed it down to one line of code.

```
db[collection].update({}, {'$inc':large_python_dictionary})
```

Although there is only ONE document in this particular database, there are a few thousand fields being updated with this one line contained in `large_python_dictionary`.

Is there something I can do to fix this or should I be looking into a different schema / different type of database?

Comment: How often are you performing this update?

Comment: Every three seconds for five minutes.

Comment: different schema would probably be better for this use case then.  are all these fields related somehow?